# Use routerLink in string value on HashMap object

Tags: angular, angular5

I store parameters translated in HashMap object on my component. But the problem is that attributes such as [routerLink] do not work or just are not interpreted by angular (v5).

My code on Component:

```
export class HomeComponent {
  public welcomeParams: object = {
    '%start_link_homepage%' : '<a [routerLink]="' + this.localize.translateRoute('/') + '">',
    '%end_link_homepage%' : '</a>'
  };

  constructor(private localize: LocalizeRouterService) { }
}
```

this.localize.translateRoute('/') return => /fr/

My code on HTML file:

```
<div [innerHTML]="'app.home.welcome.text' | translate | join | replace:welcomeParams"></div>
<!-- join & replace is pipe created by me -->
```

Replace pipe: use only replace function on string type

Join pipe: create a join between the different elements of an array

Actual result:

```
<a> Website </a>
```

Desired result:

```
<a href="/fr" ng-reflect-router-link="/fr/"> Website </a>
```

Comment: I moved your solution to its own community wiki answer.

Answer (score 0):

*Solution by OP.*

I solved my problem using jquery in a method implemented by AfterViewInit.
Example:

```
public welcomeParams: object = {
    '%start_link_homepage%': '<a class="ng-link" href="' + this.localize.translateRoute('/').slice(0, -1) + '">',
    '%end_link_homepage%': '</a>',
}

ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    let self = this;
    $('.ng-link').off().on('click', function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      console.log('Ok');
      let href = this.href.replace(/^(?:\/\/|[^\/]+)*\//, '');
      self.router.navigate([href]);
    });
  }
```

localize attribute is https://www.npmjs.com/package/localize-router